# Does Cakkavala correspond to a solar system?

Tags: buddhist-cosmology

I read the description of Cakkavala in the tipitaka, and it is translated to the term "world system". It is said there are infinite Cakkavala's and light rays emanating from its sun can illuminate the whole Cakkavala, whereas light rays emanated from the Buddha can illuminate all Cakkavala's. Wow!!!

And each Cakkavala has a sun, a moon and a mount sineru. I have few questions around this:

1. Does this imply that a Cakkavala is equivalent to a solar system as per the modern cosmology?
2. Why the description of Cakkavala does not take into account other planets in the solar system?
3. Is mount Sineru visible only to those who have advanced mental faculties and have gained the divine eye? Just wondering how come an entire mountain is not visible to us?
4. If mount Sineru was visible to all, then it should be visible to the naked eye from a person living anywhere in India, right?

Comment: Have you got a telescope?

Comment: Is this very similar to the linked question, also by you?

Comment: I keep going back and forth when it comes to contemplating and comprehending about Cakkavala, and I wanted to specifically narrow down the query here so I felt the need to post the question along with few others. I well remember I had posted a question concerning Cakkavala sometime back, but I just felt the urge to discuss and hone in on my exact query here.

Comment: Since it's too similar to the other question, I made it a duplicate. Maybe you can update the other one.